# Pivot Unpivot to create a mapping table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, unpivot

I have data in the below format, Where in the values from Column_1 are mapped to Map_1,Map_2 or Map_3. But instead of the having a mapping table, the data is present in below format where 1 marks which value from Column_1 maps to which mapping Value

```
Column_1 Map_1 Map_2 Map_3
 A         0     1    0 
 B         1     0    0
 C         1     0    0
 D         0     0    1
```

I would like to transform it to below format:

````
A   Map_2
B   Map_1
C   Map_1
D   Map_3
```
````

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unpivot Pandas Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259067/unpivot-pandas-data)

Answer (score 0):

try this with `pd.DataFrame.dot`, assuming `Column_1` is your index:

```
df.dot(df.columns)
```

If `Column_1` it's not your index, try:

```
df[df.colmuns[1:]].dot(df.columns)
```

Output:

```
A    Map_2
B    Map_1
C    Map_1
D    Map_3
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

pandas' [idxmax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) come to rescue. It returns column with maximum value, which is enough in your case:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Bird":[1,0,1,0], "Snake":[0,0,0,1], "Dog":[0,1,0,0]}) 
df.idxmax(1)
```

DataFrame:

```
   Bird Snake Dog
0   1   0   0
1   0   0   1
2   1   0   0
3   0   1   0
```

code output:

```
1      Dog
2     Bird
3    Snake
dtype: object
```

For your case:

```
df.loc[:, ["Map_1", "Map_2", "Map_3"]].idxmax(1)
```