# How to add all columns in dataframe below first column

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have excel data in following format:

```
Index 1    1     1     1
A     x    x     x     x 
B     x    x     x     x
C     x    x     x     x
```

Where x is some time stamp, but since I know meaningful data to my program would be something like:

```
Index 1    
A     x     
B     x    
C     x
A     x
B     x
C     x
.
.
4 times
```

And then I'll get sequence of x ie timestamps
Is there any way I can achieve this..?
x is just example and is not same throughout.

EDIT-----

```
TRAIN NO    901       902        901         902         901          902
DA      05:40:00    06:00:00    06:12:00    06:24:00    06:36:00    06:48:00
NWWI    05:40:00    06:02:46    06:14:36    06:26:36    06:38:36    06:50:36
NFHH    06:07:20    06:19:00    06:31:00    06:43:00    06:55:00
NFHH    06:00:00    06:12:00    06:24:00    06:36:00    06:48:00    07:00:00
NWWI    06:04:34    06:16:24    06:28:24    06:40:24    06:52:24    07:04:24
DA      06:07:20    06:19:00    06:31:00    06:43:00    06:55:00    07:07:00
```

From this table I need all columns of same name to come below first one and apply this for all columns so that I only have one column of say 901 name and row data associated shall be copied in row and since it's uniform so I know it is possible but dont know how

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unpivot Pandas Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259067/unpivot-pandas-data)

Comment: unfortunately no as i told it's not same value of x and and i need to kind of concat multiple columns into one

Comment: But `df.melt(id_vars="Index")` worked using what you have posted. May you provide sample data using the actual data types?

Comment: Added data...could you please check and see if anything can be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may concatenate columns (0,1,2) with (0,3,4), (0,5,6), etc. vertically.

**Data**

```
df.columns = ["TRAIN NO"] + ["901", "902"] * 3
print(df)    
  TRAIN NO       901       902       901       902       901       902
0       DA  05:40:00  06:00:00  06:12:00  06:24:00  06:36:00  06:48:00
1     NWWI  05:40:00  06:02:46  06:14:36  06:26:36  06:38:36  06:50:36
2     NFHH  06:07:20  06:19:00  06:31:00  06:43:00  06:55:00      None
3     NFHH  06:00:00  06:12:00  06:24:00  06:36:00  06:48:00  07:00:00
4     NWWI  06:04:34  06:16:24  06:28:24  06:40:24  06:52:24  07:04:24
5       DA  06:07:20  06:19:00  06:31:00  06:43:00  06:55:00  07:07:00
```

**Code**

```
df_ans = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, [0, 2*i+1, 2*i+2]] for i in range(int(len(df.columns)/2))], axis=0)

print(df_ans)
  TRAIN NO       901       902
0       DA  05:40:00  06:00:00
1     NWWI  05:40:00  06:02:46
2     NFHH  06:07:20  06:19:00
3     NFHH  06:00:00  06:12:00
4     NWWI  06:04:34  06:16:24
5       DA  06:07:20  06:19:00
0       DA  06:12:00  06:24:00
1     NWWI  06:14:36  06:26:36
2     NFHH  06:31:00  06:43:00
3     NFHH  06:24:00  06:36:00
4     NWWI  06:28:24  06:40:24
5       DA  06:31:00  06:43:00
0       DA  06:36:00  06:48:00
1     NWWI  06:38:36  06:50:36
2     NFHH  06:55:00      None
3     NFHH  06:48:00  07:00:00
4     NWWI  06:52:24  07:04:24
5       DA  06:55:00  07:07:00
```

Comment: Bravo, that's genius..but since we've reached here so I'll throw some more practical sample data I'm dealing it...Major change in that is that columns that we see here we can figure they are alt to each other but main data have like some hundred columns and again only few columns say some 50 columns are getting repeated and catch is there is no uniform logic so as when they'll show up again so columns goes like....101,102,103,104,102,103,102,102,101,104 etc etc for example so how can we deal with that ?

Comment: Please post another question because the situation is completely different. NOTE: The strategies to solve a problem may be fundamentally different against different data. By posting question in such a incremental way, you are making people wasting their time solving non-problems. Please post the actual question directly next time.